# Choose resolution of Image/Video capture C# Android 2023

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, video-capture

Hi All I have created a simple android application using VS and Xamarin.Forms, Mediapicker.
I have managed to capture images and videos and save in various method but would like to know if there is a way to change the resolution/quality of images and videos shot using my android app?

`var video = await MediaPicker.CaptureVideoAsync(); await LoadVideoAsync(video);`

I have seen on internet the mediapicker does not allow resolution/quality changes, and im not finding much work arounds :/

Comment: Currently, `MediaPicker` does not expose any options to set the quality or resolution. You may try to use native platform APIs to set the quality capture settings.

Comment: I have found in real phone testing using MediaPicker you can indeed use the devices interface to select the camera quality when the camera is opened for photo capture. 108M doesnt work though thinking its the png format im using in my base64 stream